# java sending email with activation link

Tags: java, email, glassfish

I think I have a quite simple question. I'm working on a web app with java and glassfish server where users can register and after they do, I want to send them an email with an activation link.

Is it possible to send mails with the java mail API without an external smtp server?

Since it is not necessary for users to answer to that mail. It seems I'm lacking basic knowledge of how sending emails works. I just want to invent some sender adress like "registration@onlineshop.com". Its obvious to me, that I would need a mail server for that domain so that one could send a message TO that adress. But if I'm just sending a mail FROM that adress, why can't I just invent the adress?

I don't want to use an external service like google or yahoo. If it's not possible can you suggest me an open source mail server that goes along with glassfish? I mean, is it possible to use glassfish as an email server? If not, what else could I use?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Simply use the javax mail library.

If you use Maven, you'd do something like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you could do something like this

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SendEmail
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {    
      // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
      String to = "abcd@gmail.com";
      String from = "registration@onlineshop.com";

      Properties properties = System.getProperties();
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      try{
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

         message.setSubject("Registration from me :)");
         message.setText("You got yourself an account. congrats");

         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that quick answer! No, I'm not using maven, is it necessary? I ran your code and it gave me a "**ConnectException:** Connection refused"

Comment: I googled again and found that I can use mac's built-in postfix mailer, which can be started from within the terminal simply by "sudo postfix start". It worked now, thanks a lot!!

Comment: @BenSkeleton Thanks for your information. (windows user here ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do.

Just call this function to send an automated email to client. 
In parameter "to" is email address to which you want to send an email.

For attaching pdf refer [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm).

I usually do it in Maven project. If you are using maven project then import following dependencies.
`https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail/1.4`

```
private void sendMail(String to, String subject, String emailBody) throws MessagingException{
    final String username = "youremail@gmail.com";
    final String password = "emailPassword";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
        }
    );

    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("shubham20.yeole@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setContent(emailBody, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```